# Need help with acceleration question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

I don't understand how to solve this question involving two constant accelerations.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have problem with this? Say sth about your reasoning.

Comment: Honestly, i just realised i have not read the question properly after trying to solve it for 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the question is pretty straight forward. For acceleration:

$$L=\frac{a_1 \cdot t_1^2}{2} \implies t_1 = \sqrt\frac{2L}{a_1} \implies v=\sqrt{2a_1\cdot L}$$

For deceleration:

$$a_2\cdot t_2+ v=0 \implies t_2=-\frac{\sqrt{2a_1\cdot L}}{a_2}$$

The minimum time is thus $t_{min}=t_1+t_2$.

Comment: thanks man, i realised i did not read the question properly after seeing your answer. i cant thank you enough after trying so hard to solve it.